# Sphinx reindexing takes several hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

What should I do to speed up Sphinx indexing (using MySQL)?
Should I use other database, noSQL database?

Note also that delta indexing is fast, only a full reindeinx process is slow.
Please explain in details. Thx!

UPDATE:
I'm reindexing over 100.000 items and my thinking-sphinx index definition looks like this

```
define_index do
    indexes [text, user(:nickname), user(:full_name)]
    has rewrites(:id), :as => :rewrite_id
    has rewrites(:user_id), :as => :rewrite_user_id
    has [rewrites(:user_id), user_id], :as => :user_id_or_rewrites_user_id
    has comments(:user_id), :as => :comments_user_id
    has simbols(:id), :as => :simbol_ids
    has followings(:follower_id), :as => :follower_id
    has follows(:followable_id), :as => :followable_id
    has created_at, :sortable => true
    has rewrites_count, :sortable => true
    has relevance, :sortable => true
    has user_id
    set_property :delta => :datetime
  end
```

Comment: Please provide a little more detail.  How many items are you indexing? Where does it seem to be spending the most time indexing? Do you have log output? I have indexed ten of thousands of articles with multiple indexed fields and it normally takes a few minutes.

Comment: @Todd: I just updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried to ascertain where most of the processing is happening?  If it's in mysql it could be that you need to better index the table. Maybe try manually running the query that sphinx is using and see how it does.  I am inclined to say this can be sped up.  I just reran a full index on 10k+ records and it took < 1 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a full index is slow. How slow?

Building a delta index is fast.

This sounds normal in my experience.

noSQL databases (last I heard @Rails 2.3.5) were kind of difficult to integrate with Rails. No SQL speeds depend on your data sets and relations.

Without more information this sounds normal.

== Edit ==

Make sure you have SQL indexes on

```
 created_at
 rewrites_count
 relevance
```

in addition to your primary keys naturally.

Comment: Shur... I know it's normal, but what should be a better way for doing it?

Comment: Yes... my database columns have indexes.

Comment: @xpepermint Do you know if the process is IO or CPU bound? If I recall correctly its multi threaded and was IO bound for my app. If IO bound, throw hardware at it.

Comment: I think i found the solution. An index was missing for one of the searchable fields. It now takes a second for 3k records. I'll see how it goes with 100k records.

Answer (score 1):

When working with thinking_sphinx always look at the SQL it generates in the real sphinx configuration file.  Run a query analyzer against all the queries it will run.  I have found you can also manipulate the queries quite a bit.

Also for one to many relationships you may need to add this:

:source => :ranged_query

It will cause the sphinx to use a separate query to gather the children rather than an outer join.  It is much faster in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

how about using Real Time indexes (with adjusting appropriate memory limit)

Comment: hum... can you give me an example?

Comment: Real-time indexes (or RT indexes for brevity) are a new backend that lets you insert, update, or delete documents (rows) on the fly.